# Generating a random number from a random number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that generates a random number from a random number generated by a Perlin noise. If you ask why I am trying to add a little bit more randomness to a random number generator and see how that would work.

Anyways my problem is from the Perlin noise random number I always get 12 digit random numbers like: 124592051214, 431268750000, 420799999999, 613979257812...

the thing is I want this function to be used just like a normal python Random function. You give the borders(a,b) and you get a random number in those borders.

So, how can I turn a 12 digit number to match the given borders? Thanks in advance

ex:

```
num = 124592051214

perlinRand(50,100)
62
```

Comment: you can randomly select some digits.

Comment: Perhaps the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) may help.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi So do you mean I can randomly choose some digits from the 12 digit number? wouldn't it be too inefficient? Because it needs to try for random numbers until it's in the wanted range. But that maybe could work.

Comment: @dlask The modulo operator crossed my mind but I couldn't think of a solution to this problem with the modulo operator.

Comment: Simplify your task for random numbers between `0` and `N-1` (inclusive). Then the modulo operator makes the work immediately. The rest is just fine tuning with some additions.

Comment: @dlask It Seems like it will work. Alright. I'll try to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
perlin_noise % (higher-lower) + lower
```

where "higher" is the higher limit of the random number you want, "lower" is the lower limit and perlin_noise is the number you generate

```
def perlinRand(lower, higher):
    perlin_noise = get_perlin_noise_random_number()
    return perlin_noise % (higher-lower) + lower

perlinRand(50, 100)
```

Comment: This definitely works. I didn't think that the solution would be this easy. I was thinking too complex. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YusufKerem The proposed approach works correctly only if the input range is much larger than the output range. Anyway, it's always reasonable to [start with simplest solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product).

Comment: @dlask You are right for the time being I don't need it for numbers that are higher than 12 digits. Will improve in the future. Thanks anyways.